# What function does 了perform in this sentence 我忘问她要电话了 ？

Tags: grammar, particles

It's a change of situation, isn't it? But what has changed? Why is 了 not used after the verb?

Answer (score 2):

It is a modal particle 了 (aka 了2) that expresses "already":

- 我忘了問他要電話 = I forgot to ask him for (his) phone number.
- 我忘了問他要電話了 = I have forgotten to ask him for (his) phone number.

The first "了" indicates the completion of action "忘"; the 了 at the end indicates you have (already) done such - "問他要電話". Similarly,

- 我問他要電話 = I ask him for (his) phone number.
- 我問他要電話了 = I've asked for his phone number.

Here is a good study material - https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Uses_of_%22le%22

Answer (score 0):

I found an aticle from Zhihu, which might solve your problem:

https://www.zhihu.com/question/25458789/answer/94693280